# How to remove margin from every element that is the last element in a row?

Tags: css

How to remove margin from every `<li>` of last column? I'm asking for every `<li>` which comes in last column when I have 9 `<li>` and 3 in each column. I'm not asking just to remove `margin` from last item of last `<li>` of a `<ul>` which I already know `:last-child { margin-right: 0 }`

And if screen is small or user resize the browser then **3 + 3 + 3** can become to **4 + 5** or **2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1**

So in any condition any `<li>` ( it can be one or more then one)  which comes in last column. I want to remove `margin-right`.

**All li are within a single ul**

```
<ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
   <li>item 3</li>
   <li>item 4</li>
   <li>item 5</li>
   <li>item 6</li>
   <li>item 7</li>
   <li>item 8</li>
   <li>item 9</li>
</ul>
```

I added jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GnUjA/1/

Comment: Can you post your html and css?  I'm guessing the `li`s are inline and all within a single `ul`?

Comment: Can you please accept an answer?

Comment: If there were ever an addition to CSS I wished for, this is it.

Answer (score 15):

Removing or adding stylings on a specific element of each row cannot be done with pure CSS unless you know exactly how many elements there are per row (via the `nth-child()` family of selectors).

## Negative Margins

What you *can* to do in the case of margins is disguise them by adding negative margins on the parent element.  This will give the illusion that your child elements fit inside the parent element while still having spacing between the individual elements:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/dwbHi

```
ul {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}

li {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Splitting the margin in half and setting it on both sides (`margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px`) may give better results than a single margin on one side (`margin-right: 10px`), particularly if your design needs to work with LRT *and* RTL directions.

Note: this may require adding `overflow-x: hidden` on an ancestor element to prevent horizontal scrolling, depending on how close the container element is positioned to the edge of the viewport.

## Media Queries

If you can reasonably predict how many items there are going to be per row, you can use media queries to target the last item in the row via `nth-child()`.  This is considerably more verbose than using negative margins, but it would allow you to make other style adjustments:

```
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 499px) {
    li:nth-child(even) {
        margin-right: 0;
        border-right: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    li:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-right: 0;
        border-right: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px) {
    li:nth-child(4n+4) {
        margin-right: 0;
        border-right: none;
    }
}
/* etc. */
```

Comment: The negative margins solution changed my life.

Comment: Negative margin works nice, but beware if you have a set width on the container - you may have to prolong it with the negative margin's length

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want (jquery):

http://jsfiddle.net/PKstQ/

If that fiddle demonstrates what you are looking to do (except with margin instead of background-color) then you can't do that with css.  You will need javascript.  If jquery is acceptable then that posted fiddle can easily be modified.  Would be relatively trivial to turn it into pure js as well.

Comment: can't we don in css with nth-child?

Comment: @Jitendra: how would CSS's `nth-child` have any knowledge of in which row, column or position the `li` was rendered? CSS has *no* conditional abilities, this needs to be done with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To me it makes more sense to give the left side of `ul` some padding that evens it out.

I added: `ul { padding-left: 10px; }` - http://jsfiddle.net/GnUjA/30/

Depends if it would be necessary but same really goes to the top:

`ul { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; }` - http://jsfiddle.net/GnUjA/31/

Answer (score 0):

I have done a simple solution for a padding 30px of divs.
I'm adding 30px to the min width to allow the expansion.

min-width: calc(100% + 30px);

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Answer rewritten after looking at sample HTML**

What you want to do is not possible with CSS. The reason is that you want to style elements *based on the rendered layout*, which CSS only allows you to work *based on the document structure*.

Something like this is only achievable with client-side scripting (Javascript), which can query rendered layout properties and act accordingly.

Comment: I'm not using table. And I'm not asking about `last-child`

Comment: @JitendraVyas: Well, telling us *what* you use would be helpful. Maybe even an HTML sample?